# Coding of arduino and ZEDF9P GNSS module

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

I have ZEDF9P AND ARDUINO and connected them Via UART.
I have written program which is showing that NMEA strings are coming in arduino and arduino is filtering out if GPS jamming is taking place. Now once GPS signals are coming LCD show GPS:ok. oNCE GPS is jammed it is giving output as GPS:INVALID
.During this time it converts to GLONASS. I want to write GLONASS ENABLED on LCD once I get signals. But my problem is that I am unable to write code for the time once GLONASS is enabled. I want that once I switch on another system The system name should come on LCD automatically but I don't know where the code is wrong. Kindly help me with the code. (I am doing it with NEO6M as well so kindly ignore baudrate)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

// Choose two Arduino pins to use for software serial
 int RXPin = 6;
 int TXPin = 7;

//Default baud of NEO-6M is 9600
int GPSBaud = 9600;

// Create a software serial port called "gpsSerial"
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(RXPin, TXPin);


#define GPSENABLE 2
byte GPSBuffer[82];
byte GPSIndex=0;
#define MAX_NMEA 200 // Max characters in NMEA Sentence to accumulate

float gpsSpeed;
void processGGA(char *nmea)
{
// TODO
}
void processGLL(char *nmea)
{
// TODO
}
void processRMC(char *nmea)
{
char *token = strtok(nmea, ",");  // Split NMEA string with ',' delimiter
if (token) // Is Token NULL?
{
int i;
for(i=0; i<7; i++) // Process Fields, truncated
{
 token = strtok(NULL, (i < 11) ? "," : "*"); // delimit based on expected termination
  if (!token) break; // NULL Token
  if (i == 1) // Field 1 Fix
  {
  lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    if (token[0] == 'A')
     { lcd.print("GPS:OK");
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);}
    else if (token[0] == 'V')
      {delay(100);
        lcd.print("GPS:INVALID");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  delay(100);
  };
  uint8_t ubx_cfg_gnss[] = {
0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x3E,0x2C,0x00, // UBX-CFG-GNSS
0x00,0x00,0x10,0x05, // 16-Channels, 5-Constellations in list
0x00,0x08,0x10,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x01, // GPS
0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01, // SBAS
0x03,0x08,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01, // GALILEO
0x05,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01, // BEIDOU
0x06,0x08,0x0E,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01, // GLONASS
0xE8,0xFE }; // compute checksum
 Serial.write(ubx_cfg_gnss,sizeof(ubx_cfg_gnss));


      }
    else
      lcd.print("GPS:UNKNOWN");
  }
  if (i == 6) // Field 6 Speed Knots (Basically a Nautical Mile, or One Arc Minute)
   { gpsSpeed = atof(token) / (3600.0 / 1852.0); // Pull as a floating point (in knots, convert to 
  m/s)
  }
  }

  }
  }
  void ProcessGPSLine()
  {
     if ((GPSBuffer[1] == 'G') && (GPSBuffer[2] == 'L') && (GPSBuffer[3] == 'G') && (GPSBuffer[4] == 
        'G') && (GPSBuffer[5] == 'A'))
   {
     lcd.print("GLGGA Detected!");
      }

    }
    void readSerialGPS()
   {
     static char receivedGPSChars[MAX_NMEA]; // buffer for received GPS data
   static int ndx = 0; // buffer index
    static boolean newGPSData = false;

    while((gpsSerial.available() > 0) && (newGPSData == false)) // Drop out at each complete line
  {
   char rc = gpsSerial.read();

Serial.write(rc); // Feed byte from GPS to the console

if (rc != '\r') { // Terminate line, CR,LF pair
  if (rc == '$') // Resync on leading '$'
    ndx = 0;
  if (rc != '\n') // Don't copy LF
    receivedGPSChars[ndx++] = rc;
  if (ndx >= MAX_NMEA) // Constrain length
    ndx = MAX_NMEA - 1;
  }
   else { // '\r'
  receivedGPSChars[ndx] = '\0'; // Terminate the string
  ndx = 0;
  newGPSData = true;
   }
 } // while
 if (newGPSData) // One new line available
 {
   static boolean gpsAlert = false;

if (gpsAlert == false)
{
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("GPS:ENABLED");
  

  gpsAlert = true;
}
 if (strncmp(receivedGPSChars, "$GPGGA", 6) == 0)
  processGGA(receivedGPSChars);
else if (strncmp(receivedGPSChars, "$GPGLL", 6) == 0)
  processGLL(receivedGPSChars);
else if (strncmp(receivedGPSChars, "$GPRMC", 6) == 0)
  processRMC(receivedGPSChars);

newGPSData = false;
 }
 }
  void setup()
 {
 // Start the Arduino hardware serial port at 9600 baud
 Serial.begin(9600);
 // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  // Start the software serial port at the GPS's default baud
  gpsSerial.begin(GPSBaud);
  }
  void loop()
  {
     readSerialGPS(); // Consume data, process sentences
  }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please edit the question and clearly state what you are attempting to do, what is happening, what you expect, what you are getting.  As it is, there is little anyone can do to help you.

Comment: I have edited it.